# Evento para detectar imagen cargada GLIDE

Tags: java, android

Estoy usando la librería **Glide** para mostrar imágenes, de esta manera:

```
GlideApp.with(this).load("https://i1.wp.com/blogthinkbig.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/shutterstock_148972376.jpg").into(imageView);
```

**Como puedo saber cuando la imagen terminó de cargarse**

Comment: Mediante onResourceReady() determinas que la imagen ha sido cargada correctamente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar los callbacks que tiene Glide. En la documentación de la misma puedes encontrar mas información o hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Glide.with(getActivity())
 .load(args.getString(IMAGE_TO_SHOW))
 .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
     @Override
     public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         return false;
     }
 })
 .into(imageFrame);
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31675796/819710

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una sentencia, puedes usar un `try catch` o un `if`

```
try {
   GlideApp.with(this).load("https://i1.wp.com/blogthinkbig.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/shutterstock_148972376.jpg").into(imageView);
} catch (Exception e) {
   Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se puedo cargar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  

     return null;
}
```

Por otro lado si quieres crear una solución mas compleja podrías usar un `Progressbar`con esto muestras la carga de la imagen en tiempo real al usuario, en cambio con la solución de arriba (`try catch`) te mostrara un mensaje al termino de la tarea.

Comment: No me funciona con lo que pusiste, primero me muestra el Toast y luego termina de descargar la imagen

Comment: Te muestra el mensaje de que no se cargó y sin embargo si lo hizo ? @programdorloco

Comment: Puse un Toast abajo del try catch, primero muestra ese toast y luego carga la imagen

Comment: si entiendo bien, solo debes ordenar el toast nada mas @programadorloco

Answer (score 0):

Usando [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), para detectar que cargamos una imagen se usa [**onResourceReady()**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets), de acuerdo a tu código, sería:

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://i1.wp.com/blogthinkbig.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/shutterstock_148972376.jpg")
            .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);

                    //*Aquí determina la carga del recurso.
                    Log.i(TAG, "La imagen ha sido cargada por Glide!");

                }
            });
```